# Key Value Pair get and put with constant time complexity (key string with 5 length)

Tags: data-structures, hashmap

Was asked to create a Key/Value pair with Get and Put, which has constant time complexity.  The key is string of length 5 and value is object.

Also NO Hash functionality (HashMap, HashSet, HashTable or others)  It has collisions.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you tagging 3 different languages?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not to use a hash function then constant time is more difficult. The easiest is if you can restrict the key to a sufficiently small set of integer values that you can simply use a directly indexed large array. Otherwise <del>an N-ary tree with large enough N, compared to the number of possible keys, that the logarithmic behavior is essentially constant.</del> if the actual number of possible keys is relatively small then you can use a tree structure and regard the few steps of searching that tree, which is formally logarithmic, as practically constant.

---

If

> **”** The key is string of length 5

means a byte string of length 5, then the key has just 40 bits. But that's roughly one thousand billion values, which on a 2016's PC is a little too much for direct array indexing.

One way to restrict it is to require that each byte is the ASCII code of a decimal digit. Then there's just 100 000 distinct key values and direct indexing of an array is feasible.

Comment: Good points, however it looks like the direct indexing of an array is the way to go.  However, the data set is too large for the memory.  Maybe it can be saved to files.